# copy the row data diagonally

Tags: sql

I have table in the below format

```
historyid  regnumber  updatedate   datecreated
1               11      2012-12-29   2012-12-22
2               11      2012-11-29   2013-11-23
```

I need to update  the `updatedate` with `historyid` 2 with `datecreated` of `historyid` one.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  What's the problem?  Is this a recurring task, for many more records?  Why are you picking ids 1 and 2?

Comment: What have you tried to do? Can you show us an example query that you are having an issue with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `historyid` is a primary key (or at least unique):

```
update the_table
  set updatedate = (select datecreated
                    from the_table
                    where historyid = 1)
where historyid = 2;
```

(You didn't tell us which DBMS you are using but the above should run on any modern DBMS)

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6b1a7/1